# Open .ts files on Android

Tags: applications, files

I am trying to open `.ts` files on my Android tablet, but it's prompting me to open with any Video Player installed on my device. `.ts` files are TypeScript files, just like `.js` JavaScript files but TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript.

I am trying to open and edit them in an app called AIDE Web.

[image: Screenshot]

If I change the extension, I am able to open the file and edit the text, but I don't want to do this.

So how can I open these files to view or edit them?

---

Device details (if relevant):

- LineageOS (Android 7.1.1)
- Rooted

Comment: .ts is a container for video files (Transport Stream) that is why Android tries to open them in a video player. Since you device is rooted you may be able to change this file association, but I have no idea how.

Comment: @Alex.S then any work around you know of

Comment: Try this https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-change-set-default-apps-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it depends on your file manager how a file will be opened. So here's a workaround. Download a file manager called [Amaze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amaze.filemanager), find the file you are looking for, press on the three dots next to the file name, and select "open with" this will allow you to open the file in any app you want to.

I only tested this with [amaze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amaze.filemanager) file manager, but I would imagine that the same options exist in other file manager apps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Now i am able to open the file only in note editors, still AIDE app is not supporting it.....but anyhow thanks for the workaround :)

Comment: If you press on "other" (second screenshot) and select AIDE app, and it tells you that it's not supported, then It means that the app was not made to support that kind of file.